# use variables of assynctask in oncreate

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i was finally able to make a connection with my webservice,

no i am able to read the data in my logcat

after that i splitted my json as required:

(here was code before the edit)

but what i don't get to work is:

(here was code before the edit)

it seems i cannot use the variable bedrijfsnaam in my oncreate class

my complete code:
        package com.example.deceunincktechniekers;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.client.*;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

 public class BTWcontrole extends Activity 
{

TextView btwuitvoer;
EditText landcode;
EditText nummer;
Button verstuur;
String land;
String num;
String antwoord;
Context btwcontrolecontext;
String jsonData;
private String bedrijfsnaam = new String();
String zoekurl = "http://www.softnaert.be/SNWebservices/SNWeb.wso/checkVat/JSON";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.btwcontrole);
        btwcontrolecontext = this;
    btwuitvoer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultaat);
    verstuur = (Button) findViewById(R.id.controleer);
    landcode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.landcode);
    nummer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btwnr);

verstuur.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    btwopvragen loaderTask = new btwopvragen();
    loaderTask.execute();

    land = landcode.getText().toString();
    num = nummer.getText().toString();
    Log.i("bedrijfsnaam in onclick", bedrijfsnaam);
    btwuitvoer.setText(bedrijfsnaam);   
}   
});};

  private class btwopvragen extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(btwcontrolecontext);
    dialog.setTitle("btwnummer ophalen");
    dialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // toegevoegde code om parameters aan de code toe te voegen
    if(!zoekurl.endsWith("?")){
            zoekurl += "?";
    };

    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new LinkedList<NameValuePair>();
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("llcountryCode", String.valueOf(land)));
    parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("llvatNumber", String.valueOf(num)));

    String parameterString = URLEncodedUtils.format(parameters, "utf-8");


    // effectieve http request met de parameters toegevoegd
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet aanvraag = new HttpGet(zoekurl + parameterString);


    // foutanalyse van de http request
    try
    {
        HttpResponse antwoord = client.execute(aanvraag);
        StatusLine statuslijn = antwoord.getStatusLine();
        int statuscode = statuslijn.getStatusCode();
        if(statuscode != 200){
            return null;
        }

        InputStream jsonStream = antwoord.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String lijn;

        while((lijn = reader.readLine())!= null){
            builder.append(lijn);

        }

        jsonData = builder.toString();
        // met de volgende lijn is de data zichtbaar in de logcat
        Log.i("btw geretourneerde data", jsonData);

        // hier beginnen we met de json data te ontmantelen
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        String bedrijfsnaam = json.getString("sCompanyName"); 
        Log.i("bedrijfsnaam in asynctask", bedrijfsnaam);


    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
}   
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Log.i("bedrijfsnaam in onpostexecute", bedrijfsnaam);   
    dialog.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    }


}


}
```

Comment: make your variables class members and your asynctask inner class of your activity class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `bedrijfsnaam` as field in the class.

```
        private JSONObject json = new JSONObject(...);//here if exists you should use default       constructor if not, you should find a way to put an argument to it.


    ...
       @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         .......

     bedrijfsnaam = json.getJSONObject("sCompanyName");
         .....
         }
    .....

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         ....
        public void onClick(View v) {
        antwoord = bedrijfsNaam;
                btwuitvoer.setText(antwoord)
        ....
}
```

Comment: i added:  private JSONObject bedrijfsnaam;    above my oncreate method and get now an nullpointerexception in my logcat

Comment: You should initialize it first.

Comment: ?? sorry, i am an beginner, what is initializing? how to do it?

Comment: JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData) this is initialization but i do not know where your jsonData variable.

Comment: these lines are already in my assynctask:` String jsonData = builder.toString();
   // met de volgende lijn is de data zichtbaar in de logcat
   Log.i("btw geretourneerde data", jsonData);
   
  
   JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
   JSONObject bedrijfsnaam = json.getJSONObject("sCompanyName");`

Comment: You should take them from method into the field area.OK i will edit the answer for you.

Comment: i thought so, afther this modification i had another error concerning the type of my returned data, now i have this type error also solved but seems i can still not return my variable from my oncreate method

Comment: Sorry i could not understand your last problem.What did program give error?Any stack-trace?Meanwhile you should not declare like this in doInBAckground method: JSONObject bedrijfsnaam = json.getJSONObject("sCompanyName"); this is wrong because this overrides the bedrijfsnaam that we declared as field.So erase the JSONObject from above code i.e:bedrijfsnaam = json.getJSONObject("sCompanyName");

Comment: i edited my code in my startpost to my latest version, my problem is i cannot find the log.i from my onclick and the log.i of the onpostexecute in my logcat, the log.i of the doinbackground works perfect

Comment: Sorry i could not find any error in your onclicklistener.Maybe other guys can find anything.Now because your problem has changed, you can ask a new question on stackoverflow and i believe that they can find a solution to you.